# background color surround image

Tags: html, css, background-color

I want the logo of my page on the top left corner surrounded by a black background. However, the background color does not cover the area on the right of the image. I am using HTML and CSS.

This is my code:

```css
#title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
#title img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" media="screen" />

<body>
  <div id="title">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE2r4.png" align="left" />
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `align="left"` attribute. It acts similar as if you made image `float: left`, however you never clear the float after so the parent collapses and you simply can't see background:

```css
#title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
#title img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" media="screen" />

<body>
  <div id="title">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE2r4.png" />
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to make logo left-aligned you should use `text-align: left` of the `#title`, it will work properly because img is inline-block by default.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a display rule to your title element so that it actually gets a placement in the flow:

```css
#title {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
#title img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" media="screen" />

<body>
  <div id="title">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE2r4.png" align="left" />
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```